# Finding coefficients in polynomial given three tangents

Tags: polynomials, tangent-line

I am stuck with a problem I simply cannot solve.

I have to find the coefficients of a quadratic polynomial given three tangents. The problem is stated as follows:

The three lines described by the equations

$y_1(x)=-4x-16.5$

$y_2(x)=2x-4.5$

$y_3(x)=6x-16.5$

are all tangents to a quadratic polynomial $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$

Determine the values of the coefficients a, b & c.

I simply cannot solve this problem, I've been at it for a long time. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Edit: I'm including the way I tried to solve it. I didn't get super far.

Given the polynomial $p(x)$ I know that $p'(x)=2ax+b$

Therefore, the following is true for the three points with x-values of $x_1, x_2 $ and $x_3$, where the lines $y_1, y_2$ and $y_3$ are tangent to the parabola:

$-4=2ax_1+b$

$2=2ax_2+b$

$6=2ax_3+b$

That's all I've managed to do. I've also found the points where the three lines intersect (well, three points two of the lines intersect), but I can't think of how to use that for anything.

Comment: Show anyway what you tried. I can give a solution using derivatives, but maybe it is not the solution you want.

Comment: Welcome to SE! Even if your attempts didn't work, you should absolutely include them in your post - people can advise you better that way!

Comment: @N74 I have now included my failed solution :) As you can see, I thought of using derivatives as well, but I can't get further.

Comment: My maths teacher (I'm in the last year of Danish "high school") gave it to us for tomorrow. He said that it was definitely doable.

Answer (score 4):

If we have a parabola $$ y = a x^2 + b x + c  $$ and a line $$ y = mx + d,$$
they are tangent if
$$  b^2 - 4ac = -4da + 2mb  - m^2  $$ as then the parabola
$$ y = a x^2 + (b-m) x + (c -d)  $$ has a double root, i.e. is a constant times a square, $$ a (x+p)^2 $$
Might as well write this: I fixed
$$  \Delta = b^2 - 4 a c $$
and then had three equations
$$   -4da + 2mb = m^2 + \Delta $$
by plugging in the values from the three lines $ y = mx + d.$ I expected bigger problems, but just taking the differences of two of the equations cancels the extra unknown $\Delta,$ alowing us to find $a,b$ quickly. From that, we finally get a value for $\Delta,$ after which we have one equation for $c$

$$ 66a - 8 b = 16 + \Delta \; ,    $$
$$ 66a + 12 b = 36 + \Delta \; ,    $$
$$ 18a + 4 b = 4 + \Delta \; .    $$
Second minus first gives $b.$ Plug in the $b$ value, then subtract second minus third, which gives $a.$ Plug both into any of the three to find $\Delta.$ Finally, $c = \frac{b^2 - \Delta}{4a}$

Answer (score 2):

Note that if a line and a quadratic are tangent $mx+d=ax^2+bx+c$ then the following quadratic will have discriminant zero
\begin{eqnarray*}
ax^2+(b-m)x+c-d=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
This will lead to $3$ equations for $a,b,c$ that are easily solved giving

> $(a,b,c)=(1/2,1,-4)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite follow, however: what are the three equations for a, b and c that you mention?

Comment: \begin{eqnarray*}
(b+4)^2=2a(c+33) \\
(b-2)^2=2a(c+9) \\
(b-6)^2=2a(c+33)
\end{eqnarray*}
combine the first & the third of these equations & you will rapidly yield a value for $b$.

Comment: Donald I get different final abc values, although still all rational and easily found... I kept the discriminant $\Delta = b^2 - 4ac \; $ as an unknown until the end, began with three $  \Delta = -4da + 2mb  - m^2  $  or $-4da + 2mb = m^2 + \Delta $

Comment: where does $2a(c+n)$ come from? I recall that the discriminant is equal to $b^2-4ac$, which in this case would yield something like $(b-m)^2=4a(c-d)$

I would think it would either be that or $(b-m)^2=2a(2c-2d)$

Comment: @WillJagy You are right ... I had made an error in the algebra $ c \rightarrow 2c$ ... I have corrected my values?

Comment: That is still not what I found, and I have now made careful pictures.... Let me edit in the three equations that give $(a,b)$

Comment: I get 1/2, 1 and -4 for a,b,c. 2ax+b = -4 at x=-5; 2 at x = 1 and 6 at x = 5 with x and y values being the same for tangent lines and parabola at these tangent points.

Comment: Sorry chaps ... I had made a total cabbage of the arithmetic ... try this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/g3mvmk7t83 @PhilH

Comment: That's a neat program. Could have saved me a couple of pages of scribbling :)

Comment: @PhilH You will love desmos, once you have your graph, do a screen snip & then include the image in your answers ... looks very cool $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 1):

Given any two tangents to a parabola of the form $y = f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c,$ the $x$-coordinate of the intersection of the tangent lines will be midway between the $x$-coordinates of the tangent points.

Working out the intersection points of the three lines, we can see that
the intersection of $y = y_1(x)$ and $y = y_2(x)$ occurs at $x = -2$
and the intersection of $y = y_2(x)$ and $y = y_3(x)$ occurs at $x = 3.$
Let

- $x = x_1$ at the tangent point with $y = y_1(x)$;
- $x = x_2$ the tangent point with $y = y_2(x)$; and
- $x = x_3$ the tangent point with $y = y_3(x).$

Due to the $y$-coordinates and slopes at the intersection points, it is clear that $x_1 < -2 < x_2 < 3 < x_3$;
moreover, $-2$ is midway between $x_1$ and $x_2$ and $3$ is midway between $x_2$ and $x_3.$
It follows that 
$$x_3 - x_1 = 2\left(\frac{x_3 + x_2}2 - \frac{x_2 + x_1}2\right)
= 2(3 - (-2)) = 10.$$

The tangency condition implies that $f'(x_1) = y_1'(x) = -4$ and
$f'(x_3) = y_3'(x) = 6.$
But $f'(x) = 2ax + b,$ 
so $20a = 2a(x_3 - x_1) = f'(x_3) - f'(x_1) = 10,$ 
and therefore $a = \frac12.$
It is then a relatively straightforward exercise to find the other two coefficients.